# running multiple macros in order across multiple excel workbooks - vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have multiple excel workbooks each representing a days data, each workbook has multiple sheets representing each event on the day..

i need to run 6 macros in order across each sheet in a workbook and then move on to the next workbook (all the workbooks are in the same folder on the desktop)

at the moment im using this (below) to run the macros in order across all the sheets but im having trouble trying to get somthing to run across all of the workbooks

```
Sub RUN_FILL()
Dim sh As Worksheet

For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
sh.Activate

Call macro_1
Call macro_2  
Call macro_3  
Call macro_4  
Call macro_5  
Call macro_6

Next sh
End Sub
```

any idea how i might do this ?

Comment: Are all the workbooks are initially open, or you want to open / process / close each in turn?  Also does the order the workbooks are processed matter?

Comment: The workbooks are all initially closed, apart from one where id run them from, the workbook order does not matter, just the order in which the macros are run on the individual sheets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not have your macros so I have created dummy macros that output some values to the Immediate window for every sheet of every workbook (except the workbook containing the macro).

You code appears to depend on the output macro activating each worksheet.  This is bad practice.  I pass the workbook and the worksheet name to the the macros.  I output the value of cell A1 (`.Cells(1, 1).Value`) to show how it is done.

I hope this is enough to get you started.  Ask if anything is unclear.

```
Option Explicit
Sub ControlCall()

  Dim FileNameCrnt As String
  Dim InxWSheet As Long
  Dim MsgErr As String
  Dim PathCrnt As String
  Dim RowReportCrnt As Long
  Dim WBookCtrl As Workbook
  Dim WBookOther As Workbook
  Dim WSheetNameOtherCrnt As String

  If Workbooks.Count > 1 Then
    ' It is easy to get into a muddle if there are multiple workbooks
    ' open at the start of a macro like this.  Avoid the problem.
    Call MsgBox("Please close all other workbooks " & _
                "before running this macro", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Set WBookCtrl = ActiveWorkbook

  ' Assume all the workbooks to be processed are in the
  ' same folder as the workbook containing this macro.
  PathCrnt = WBookCtrl.Path

  ' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
  If Right(PathCrnt, 1) <> "\" Then
    PathCrnt = PathCrnt & "\"
  End If

  FileNameCrnt = Dir$(PathCrnt & "*.xl*")

  Do While FileNameCrnt <> ""

    If FileNameCrnt <> WBookCtrl.Name Then
      ' Consider all workbooks except the one containing this macro
      Set WBookOther = Workbooks.Open(PathCrnt & FileNameCrnt)

      For InxWSheet = 1 To WBookOther.Worksheets.Count
        WSheetNameOtherCrnt = WBookOther.Worksheets(InxWSheet).Name

        Call macro_1(WBookOther, WSheetNameOtherCrnt)
        Call macro_2(WBookOther, WSheetNameOtherCrnt)
        Call macro_3(WBookOther, WSheetNameOtherCrnt)
        Call macro_4(WBookOther, WSheetNameOtherCrnt)
        Call macro_5(WBookOther, WSheetNameOtherCrnt)
        Call macro_6(WBookOther, WSheetNameOtherCrnt)
      Next
      WBookOther.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
 FileNameCrnt = Dir$()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
Sub macro_1(WBookOther As Workbook, WSheetNameOtherCrnt As String)

  With WBookOther
    With .Worksheets(WSheetNameOtherCrnt)
      Debug.Print "1 " & WBookOther.Name & " " & _
                  WSheetNameOtherCrnt & " " & .Cells(1, 1).Value
    End With
  End With

End Sub
Sub macro_2(WBookOther As Workbook, WSheetNameOtherCrnt As String)

  With WBookOther
    With .Worksheets(WSheetNameOtherCrnt)
      Debug.Print "2 " & WBookOther.Name & " " & _
                  WSheetNameOtherCrnt & " " & .Cells(1, 1).Value
    End With
  End With

End Sub
Sub macro_3(WBookOther As Workbook, WSheetNameOtherCrnt As String)

  With WBookOther
    With .Worksheets(WSheetNameOtherCrnt)
      Debug.Print "3 " & WBookOther.Name & " " & _
                  WSheetNameOtherCrnt & " " & .Cells(1, 1).Value
    End With
  End With

End Sub
Sub macro_4(WBookOther As Workbook, WSheetNameOtherCrnt As String)

  With WBookOther
    With .Worksheets(WSheetNameOtherCrnt)
      Debug.Print "4 " & WBookOther.Name & " " & _
                  WSheetNameOtherCrnt & " " & .Cells(1, 1).Value
    End With
  End With

End Sub
Sub macro_5(WBookOther As Workbook, WSheetNameOtherCrnt As String)

  With WBookOther
    With .Worksheets(WSheetNameOtherCrnt)
      Debug.Print "5 " & WBookOther.Name & " " & _
                  WSheetNameOtherCrnt & " " & .Cells(1, 1).Value
    End With
  End With

End Sub
Sub macro_6(WBookOther As Workbook, WSheetNameOtherCrnt As String)

  With WBookOther
    With .Worksheets(WSheetNameOtherCrnt)
      Debug.Print "6 " & WBookOther.Name & " " & _
                  WSheetNameOtherCrnt & " " & .Cells(1, 1).Value
    End With
  End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code outline:

```
For each file in folder  ' I'd use the FileSystemObject for this
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open file 
    For Each sh in wb.worksheets
        ....
    Next
    wb.save
    wb.close
Next
```