# Workbook is not closing when using Workbook.Close method

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to open and then close a workbook but my problem is after using Workbook.close method the workbook remains open and can only be killed by task manager.
I found the answer from the below link [VBA won't close workbooks opened programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10012199/vba-wont-close-workbooks-opened-programatically?rq=1)
but for my application it doesn't work...
Here the code:

```
Private Function writeInWB(myFile as String) As Variant
    Dim xl0 As New Excel.Application
    Dim xlwBBGTerm As New Excel.Workbook 
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xlwBBGTerm = xl0.Workbooks.Open(myFile)
    GoTo ErrorHandling
ErrorHandling:
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
If xl0.Workbooks.Count > 0 Then
    xlwBBGTerm.Close SaveChanges:=False
    xl0.Quit
End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more detail on exactly what you're trying to do, it's hard to be more specific, but in princple if you close all the open workbooks then quit the application, it ought to shut down. Try somethign like this:

```
Public Sub CloseAllWorkbooks()

    Dim wbk As Workbook
    For Each wbk In Application.Workbooks
        wbk.Close False
    Next

    Application.Quit

End Sub
```

Another reason why the application might not shut down is if another process still holds COM references to objects within the application.

Comment: What could another COM reference be? For the moment I only have the "GoTo" which is executed and then the execution goes to 'ErrorHandling' directly. The executing WorkBook has other things running but no other workbooks.