# How to copy several Excel sheets to 1 variant in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I use the following code in Excel VBA to copy a Excel sheet for calculation:

```
Dim Store1Sheet() As Variant

Store1Sheet = Range("A1:D99")
```

Please would you advise how to copy several Excel sheets to 1 variant, say StoreMultiSheet.  Many thanks.

Comment: Derek Ko, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you be more specific? There are many SO articles out there on moving data from one excel document to another: Example 1: [Copy values to one workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782189/excel-vba-loop-through-cells-and-copy-values-to-another-workbook). Example 2: [Collate all worksheets to a single file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351961/fetching-the-data-from-multiple-excel-to-the-main-excel). Example 3: [Copy worksheets to workbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6195566/copying-worksheets-from-one-excel-document-to-another).

Answer (score 1):

Technically what you are doing is storing an array of the values of each cell in that range within a Variant.

To do what you're asking to do, you'll need to make an array of those arrays. For instance, say you were going to have to do something like this which assumes an array base of 0:

```
Dim Multisheet() As Variant
Dim x As Integer
ReDim Multisheet(Sheets.Count - 1)
For x = 0 To Sheets.Count - 1
    Multisheet(x) = Sheets(x + 1).Range("A1:D99")
Next
```

This will generate one variant array which contains a variant array of values for each cell in the range "A1:D99" for every sheet in your workbook.

To access them, you'll need to use `Multisheet(x)` and that will be equivalent to the `Store1Sheet` you are used to using.

I recommend looking at some of the linked questions that JackOrangeLantern provided as this method feels rather ackward.